# Calculate the time for Sync in Two micro service using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, queue

I have Scripts Two API:

- Post API
- Get API

I need to calculate The time have to **sync between** First API and Second API and Calculate the Time its take to sync , In simply way I need to hit the Get API until I get Success response and Calculate the time for all these request Until Success for These hits  , is there a way to do that using Jmeter ?

Comment: it's absolutely unclear what you want. Please try to provide exact scenario (even in pseudo code), as well as more details on your script.

Answer (score 0):

Organize your Test Plan as follows:

- [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) - to measure the duration of the whole requests sequence

  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) - to loop the "First API" unless you get Success

    - Post API

      - [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) - to get "success" criteria
  - Get API